# How to describe the enthalpy of acid dissociation in aqueous solutions?

Tags: acid-base, enthalpy, calorimetry

How to describe the enthalpy of acid dissociation in aqueous solutions?
If we had a weak acid "PB" that dissociates to give a proton and a conjugate base. Classically it would be described like the following:

[image]

Unfortunately, things aren't that simple in aqueous solutions. Each of the dissociated molecules will have a charge which will change its polarity and water hydration (solvation).

a better way would be to describe dissociation in gas phase then the solvation of each:
[image]

[image]

Is this description accurate? Is the enthalpy of protonation measured by calorimetry or calculated by the Van't Hoff analysis the "dissociation" or the "Ionization"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid_dissociation_constant This link may help.